# xbtit annouce external without pid

Tags: php, bittorrent

I install the script "[xbtit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xbtit/)" and I wish uses php announce with external torrent.

When I send a new torrent external, everything runs fine but when I add the .torrent in my client, I receive an error message telling me to reload the torrent with PID, yet it is an external torrent and I deactivate deny the setting tracker!

If anyone know of a solution.

Comment: What version of xbtit you use and what is the message that you have in your torrent client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove (or comment) this part in `announce.php`:

```
if ($pid=="" || !$pid)
   show_error("Please redownload the torrent. PID system is active and pid was not found in the torrent");
}
```

it should work